# MS SQL Server 2012 drives

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am buying machine for MS SQL Server 2012 Standard and I have questions about drives and performance.

How to locate OS, database, logs, backup on WD RE4 500GB and Intel SSD DC S3500 120GB?

- OS, logs and backup on WD RE4 and database on SSD?
- OS, logs,database on SSD and backup on RE4?
- OS, backup on RE4 and database logs on SSD?

There are many combination, please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to have the os, database and translog on the ssd, Id definately do that. Backup can be done on the slower but larger drive.

If you need to offload the ssd more, I think I would put the OS on the slow drive since the translog is as important as the DB (unless you have a read-only database...)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. That is ERP database and web shop connected to it, so there will be writes as well. I think I will do OS, backup to RE4 and database, logs on SSD. Is there any prediction in database-trans. logs size ratio?

Comment: No, that depends on the number of transactions and how often you backup (with clearing the log)